# Proof that $T: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ is compact with $T(x) = \left(\frac{x_1}{1},\frac{x_2}{2},\dots\right)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Proof that $T: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ is compact with $T(x) = \left(\frac{x_1}{1},\frac{x_2}{2},\dots\right)$

I think that i need to prove that this function is continous and then look whether compact sets stay compact under the image. But i get stuck on two things:

1) how do closed/open sets in $l^2$ look like. I can probably take the open and closed balls and look at the inverses, but are these balls always closed/open in a metric space?

2) which definition of compactness is better to use here. The fact that every open cover of some set A has a finite subcovering or the fact that every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $l^2$ has a subsequence that converges in $l^2$?

Kees

Comment: Continuous functions *always* map compact sets to compact sets. What it means for $T$ to be a *compact operator* is that any *bounded* set is mapped to a relatively compact set--i.e. a set whose closure is compact.

Comment: the (closed) unit ball $\overline B$ is mapped into itself and so $\overline T(B)\subseteq  \overline B$

Comment: i proved that T is a linear transformation and ||T(x)|| < ||x||. So i got the continuity now :)

Comment: The definition you propose in (2) for compcactness is for sets. $T$ is a linear function. You need to find a definition for a compact linear function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It  is  a  [compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) because it is  a norm operator   limit of  a  sequence of  [finite  rank operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553313/finite-dimensional-range-implies-compact-operator) $$T_{n}=(x_{1},x_{2}/2,\ldots, x_{n}/n,0,0,\ldots)$$

Another reason: $TT^{*}$ is  a  trace  class operator hence $T$ is compact, as a  consequense of polar decomposition theorem and the fact that the space of compact operators is  an ideal in $B(H)$.

Comment: In fact $\vert \vert T- T_n\vert \vert \leq {1\over n+1}$