# Showing compactness that involves unilateral shift

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $V:l^2(\mathbb{N})\to l^2(\mathbb{N})$ be the *unilateral shift*, the unique bounded operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ that satisfies
$$
Ve_n=e_{n+1}
$$
, where $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Show that $V^*V-VV^*$ is compact.

Attempt:

I tried to show $V^*e_n = e_{n-1}$ for $n>1$ and $V^*e_1=e_1$

We have that $\langle V^*e_n, e_m \rangle =\langle e_n, Ve_m \rangle  =\langle e_n, e_{m+1} \rangle = \delta_{n,m+1}$.

Now  $\langle V^*e_n,x\rangle = \langle e_n, Vx \rangle  =\langle e_n, V\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}  }x_ke_k \rangle =\langle e_n, \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}  }x_kVe_k \rangle=\langle e_n, \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}  }x_ke_{k+1} \rangle $.

Then I got stuck here... I feel like it's some simple manipulation of inner product, but I just couldn't get what I wanted.

Also, to show compactness, I want to use that [finite dimensional range implies compact operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553313/finite-dimensional-range-implies-compact-operator).

So I have to show  $V^*V-VV^*$ has a finite rank.

If we prove that  $V^*e_n = e_{n-1}$ for $n>1$, then we have $V^*V-VV^* = I - VV^*$.

Then I got stuck proving that $I - VV^*$ has a finite rank.

Could someone help me to finish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got wrong is that $V^*e_1=0$.

You can easily show that
$$
(I-VV^*)e_n=\begin{cases} e_1,& \ n=1\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ n>1\end{cases}
$$
Then its obvious that $I-VV^* $ has finite rank.